# What should use bgcolor or background-color?

Tags: html, css, background

I tried to find it everywhere but not able to find a perfect explanation about it.

At some codes we see `bgcolor` to set background color like this

```
bgcolor="#FFFFFF"
```

and some uses `background-color` or `background` like this

```
element{
    background-color:#fff
}
```

I know that `bgcolor` is a html attribute and `background-color` is css but which is best to use and is there any difference?

Comment: `bgcolor` is a HTML attribute whereas `background-color` is a CSS property.

Comment: https://devdocs.io/html/attributes#bgcolor-attribute -> 

Note: This is a legacy attribute. Please use the CSS background-color property instead.

Comment: It wasn't me so I can only assume that it is due to *lack of research*.

Comment: i already know `bgcolor` is html attribute and `background-color` is css but which is the best and what is the different?

Comment: The difference is that you should not use html attributes to style your elements. Those functions are legacy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `bgcolor` attribute was superseded by CSS in 1996.

CSS background properties:

- Are more reusable
- Have a higher priority than presentational attributes
- Take a wider selection of values (including translucent ones)
- Can be stored in an external stylesheet and cached between requests
- Apply more consistently across different element types

Answer (score 6):

`bgcolor` is an html attribute, deprecated by the W3C since HTML4 in favor of CSS styles. `background-color` is a CSS property, that can be short-handed with `background`, together with other `background-` properties

e.g.

```
background-color: #fff;
background: #fff;
background: #fff url('foo.png') center center no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 3):

If I remember well, `bgcolor` is an HTML attribute, hopefully nobody uses it today. You should use `background-color` in CSS as you wrote above.